# How to add objective one by one

Tags: optimization, gurobi

I have a gurobi optimization problem, now I set the objective using `quicksum(quicksum ...)` but it takes a long time for the objective to be added, I want to add the objective one by one to check where it might go wrong, how should I do it?

I have no idea yet. I am considering using a bunch of for loops.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.